[Error]: The workbook cannot be opened or repaired by Microsoft Excel because it is corrupt
I use Python code to write to an Excel file, where each loop iteration writes a value to the file 'report.xlsx'. The program runs normally until I unexpectedly kill it from the terminal, and after that, when I try to open the 'report.xlsx' file, it shows an error message: 'The workbook cannot be opened or repaired by Microsoft Excel because it is corrupt.' I suspect that killing the program during the execution of the 'wb = load_workbook(file_excel)' command might have affected the workbook. I have tried many ways, but I still cannot restore the workbook. There are many values written in the Excel file, so I want to restore it.
This is my code and error
enter image description here
enter image description here
I've tried many methods but with no success. I want to restore the workbook to keep the Excel file intact.

What did you try? did you try delete the file and rewrite it again?
What is you error? You attached a link to the error but it is not full, it is cut in the middle
Next time- for code you have a tag of code, so we can see it in the message, not a picture, so we can copy paste it to our coeds, and don't cut the pictures so we can see the whole picture.

Golden rule. if you are testing code never do so on a file you cannot lose. Always make a backup first. Sounds like this is simply a case of a corrupted XLSX file and now if you cannot open it in Excel there is probably nothing you can do. XLSX files are zipped xml files so you may be able to open the Sheet XML file(s) and retrieve some of the data but unless you really know what you're doing probably not much chance of rescuing the file (even if you do know what you are doing).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In the Open dialogue screen in Excel, have you tried clicking the little arrow next to the Open button, then selecting Open and Repair...? This does occasionally work, even when the "can't be repaired by Excel" message is shown.

If that doesn't work then your chance of success depends on how corrupt the workbook is. If the file size looks sensible then you might be lucky. Your best bet is probably to share the file somehow.
